# Need store procedure to calculate from these two tables

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I should do this in xampp need an sp structure for this as i am a beginner if possible help to give complete sp for this scenario with detailed explanantion. Other structure like crud operations has been done with php,javascript

```
1. SELECT `cid`, `parent_cat`, `category_name`, `category_life`, `status` FROM `categories`
2. SELECT `pid`, `cid`, `bid`, `product_name`, `product_price`, `product_stock`, `added_date`, `p_status`, `loc`, `in_no`, `gst_no`, `cgst`, `sgst`, `igst`, `total`, `depre`, `pur_from` FROM `products`
```

From the above two table's i should fetch record and calculate those fields and insert in the below table:

```
3. SELECT `elapsed_yend`, `remaining_days`, `depreciation_cur`, `current_wdv`, `depreciation_next`, `next_wdv`, `accumulate_depre`, `sale_amount`, `pro_los`, `end_date` FROM `calculation`
```

Example, these calculation should happen in products table:

```
CGST:
    cgst = product_price * 09
    sgst = product_price * 09
    igst = product_price * 09

if status is 1 it should calculate  igst other cgst,sgst must be 0(zero)
             0 it should calculate  cgst,sgst other igst  must be 0(zero)

        Depreciation Amount:

            depre = product_price + .5(cgst+sgst+igst)


Elapsede year end :
        elapsed_yend = added_date(from products table (No:2)) till every year 31/March/xxxx.

        Number of days between these two dates

    remaining_days = category_life - (date difference between added_date(from products (No:1)) till date)

    category_life(from categories table (No:1))Ex:mobile it's life will be 1080 days.

    Current Year depreciation:
        depreciation_cur  = (depre/category_life)*elapsed_yend

    Current Year Written down value:

        current_wdv  = depre - depreciation_cur

    Next Year depreciation :

        depreciation_next = (depre / category_life) * D
        D = days difference between every year 01/April/xxxx till end_date(from calculation table)

    Next Year Written down value:   

        next_wdv = current_wdv - depreciation_next

    Accumulate Depreciation :

        accumulate_depre = depreciation_cur + depreciation_next
```

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: I tried to fix your question, but honestly: I gave up. It is absolutely not clear how things should be grouped together here. Two things. A) you want others to spend their free time to help with your problem, so you please use that preview window and the *edit* help information to write up a human readable question. B) it would be good to include your own efforts to solve the problem, dont expect others to do you work just because you dumped your requirements here (and as said: you dumped them in way that motivate noone to help you).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53130298/how-to-write-store-procedure-for-this

Comment: If you have a link you worked with, include that in your question. Beyond that, I *told* you what the problem with your question is. Putting a link into comments ... doesn't help with the terrible formatting of your input.

Comment: No i have formatted and given my question and also i am a beginner so i am trying to my extend but i couldnt crack it'. So please help me

Comment: Just see how I formatted the first lines (4 spaces of indent turn stuff into "code" formatting). There is also a preview window that you can use to see your changes.  SO: make sure that you only indent where it is necessary. I understand that you are new here. But again: you should understand that it takes time to write a proper question. You should be willing to spend that time, otherwise people are rarely motivated to spend their time looking at your confusing input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have cracked it and it is working fine as of now.

```
BEGIN
DECLARE cur_depre,cur_wtvalue,next_depre,next_wtvalue,accum_depre,pro_loss double(20,2);
DECLARE days,next_diff int;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS calc AS (SELECT p.pid,p_date,days,next_diff,cur_depre,cur_wtvalue,next_depre,next_wtvalue,accum_depre,pro_loss,c.cid,p.added_date,c.category_life,p.depre,p.sale_status,p.sale_date,p.sale_amount from products p,products d,categories c WHERE p.pid=d.pid AND p.cid=c.cid 
 );
 INSERT INTO calc (PID) 
SELECT PID FROM products WHERE PID NOT IN (SELECT PID FROM calc);
UPDATE calc set days = datediff(p_date,added_date);
UPDATE calc set days = 0 WHERE datediff(p_date,added_date) < 0;
UPDATE calc set next_diff = datediff(sale_date,DATE_ADD(p_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY) );
UPDATE calc set next_diff = datediff('2019-03-31',added_date) WHERE added_date>p_date;
UPDATE calc set cur_depre = (depre/category_life)*datediff(p_date,added_date);

UPDATE calc set cur_depre = 0 where (depre/category_life)*datediff(p_date,added_date)<0;

UPDATE calc set cur_wtvalue =(depre-(depre/category_life)*datediff(p_date,added_date)); 

UPDATE calc set cur_wtvalue = 0 WHERE added_date>p_date;

UPDATE calc set next_depre =( (depre/category_life)*datediff(sale_date,DATE_ADD(p_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY) )) where added_date < p_date;

UPDATE calc set next_depre =( (depre/category_life) * datediff('2019-03-31',added_date)) WHERE added_Date > p_date;

UPDATE calc SET next_wtvalue = depre -(depre/category_life)*datediff(p_date,added_date) - (( (depre/category_life)*datediff(sale_date,DATE_ADD(p_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY) )) );
UPDATE calc SET next_wtvalue = depre - (( (depre/category_life) * datediff('2019-03-31',added_date)))  WHERE added_date>p_date;

UPDATE calc SET accum_depre = ((depre/category_life)*datediff(p_date,added_date))+( (depre/category_life)*datediff(sale_date,DATE_ADD(p_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY) )) ;
UPDATE calc SET accum_depre =( (depre/category_life) * datediff('2019-03-31',added_date))  WHERE added_Date > p_date;

UPDATE calc SET pro_loss = sale_amount-(depre -(depre/category_life)*datediff(p_date,added_date) - (( (depre/category_life)*datediff(sale_date,DATE_ADD(p_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY) )) ) ); 

UPDATE calc SET pro_loss = 0 WHERE sale_status=0;
SELECT * from calc;

END
```