# How can I calculate these date difference,multiplication in a MySQL stored procedure?

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I am trying to implement a procedure within mysql that returns the number of days based on a calculation. The purchase date (added_date) is passed in and then the calculation is done. Should be relatively straight forward but I cannot seem to get it to work. I am not sure if this is an appropriate situation for a "select statement" and I apologize if this is extremely simple but this is my first run at procedures.

If somebody could please tell me what should i do so, it would be much appreciated.

Thanks!

I have a table called "**calculation**"(TABLE 3) that contains the field "elap_yend " (int) which is currently empty until the stored procedure is called.

Table 1:

```
cid     parent_cat      category_name            category_life 
22        0             Office Equipment-M'         1080            
23        0             Office Equipment-O'         1800            
24        0             F & F'                      3600            
25        0             Staff assets',              1800            
27        0             Motor vehicle',             2880            
28        0             Air conditioner'            5400            
29        0             Land & Building',           2160            
30        0             Temporary Partition         365         
31        0             Electrical Fittings         3600            
32        0             Generator'                  5400            
33        0             Software'                   1800            
34        0             Computer-N'                 2160            
35        24            chair'                      3600
```

Tble 2:

```
pid    cid    product_name      product_price   added_date  cgst  sgst igst  total      depre 
60      22    RHFL\test\001         20000       2018-11-02  1800  1800  0     23600     o
61      27    RHFL\test\002         13500       2018-11-02  2345  2345  0     15930     12
62      29    RHFL\test\003         65000       2018-11-02  2345  2345  0     76700     12
63      31    RHFL\test\004         10000       2018-11-02  2345  2345  0     1180      12
64      24    RHFL\test\005         10000       2018-11-02  2345  2345  0     11800      1
65      24    RHFL\test\006         13500       2018-11-02  2345  2345  0     15930     12
66      34    RHFL\test\007         13500       2018-11-02  2345  2345  0     15930     12
67      22    RHFL\test\008         65004       2018-11-02  2345  2345  0     76704     12
68      25    RHFL\test\009         10000       0000-00-00  2345  2345  0     11800     12
69      22    RHFL\test\010         65000       0000-00-00  2345  2345  0     76700     10
                                                                                        70
```

Table 3: output of the stored procedure should reflect in the below table:

```
   end_date   elap_yend rem_days depre_cur cur_wdv depre_next next_wdv acc_depre    
   2018-11-02     0                 0      0         0          0        0
```

Output Calculation :

Above is the sample output with zero. It is not the exact output but whenever i am calling the stored procedure it should do these below calculation.

```
   DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE calculationTemp(
    in  till_yend date, 
    )
BEGIN
    DECLARE till_yend date;

    SELECT datediff(now(),added_date) INTO till_yend
    FROM products

    IF till_yend > 0 THEN
 SET till_yend = select datediff(now(),added_date) from products;
        ELSEIF till_yend < 0 THEN
        SET till_yend = 0;
    END IF;
 insert into calculationTemp
END$$
```

Calculation Workings:

Elapsede year end :
        elapsed_yend = added_date(from products table (No:2)) till every year 31/March/xxxx.

Number of days between these two dates

remaining_days = category_life - (date difference between added_date(from products (No:1)) till date)

category_life(from categories table (No:1))Ex:mobile it's life will be 1080 days.

Current Year depreciation:
depreciation_cur  = (depre/category_life)*elapsed_yend

- Current Year Written down value:

  current_wdv  = depre - depreciation_cur
- Next Year depreciation :
          depreciation_next = (depre / category_life) * D
          D = days difference between every year 01/April/xxxx till end_date(from calculation table)
- Next Year Written down value:

  next_wdv = current_wdv - depreciation_next
- Accumulate Depreciation :

  accumulate_depre = depreciation_cur + depreciation_next

Comment: you can use use now() instead of DECLARE today TIMESTAMP variable

Comment: can you help to write the store procedure as per requirement. At least with one calculation so i can do for other

Comment: DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE calculation(@ added_date DATE)
BEGIN
SELECT DATEDIFF(now(),added_date)/365 AS elapsed_yend 
FROM products;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
pass the value of added parameter as
from the parameter of this stored procedure or Where you call the stored procedure there pass the value :call calculation('2018-06-25');

Comment: pass the value in yyyy-MM-dd format

Comment: in above stored procedure use this CAST(DATEDIFF(now(),added_date) as int)/365 as elapsed_yend

Comment: i want to give if condition in my store procedure. Ex: if datediff(now(),added
_date) >0 { return number of days} else { return 0 }. If you could please tell me what should i do so, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: you can use case statement .for ex : case  WHEN datediff(now(),added _date) >0 THEN  { return number of days} ELSE  { return 0 } also my sql if is also used in query like use case stement but syntax is different

Comment: Please explain with my code i can't able get your point as i am a beginner

Comment: In your select query use this: SELCE case WHEN datediff(now(),added _date) >0 THEN { return number of days} ELSE 0 END AS till_yend  from yourtablename in return number of days replace what you want

Comment: Please edit my code and give explanation i couldnt get you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got My answer posting here to get any idea regarding to improve  my store procedure. Thank You!!!

```
 BEGIN
    DECLARE cur_depre,cur_wtvalue,next_depre,next_wtvalue,accum_depre,pro_loss double(20,2);
    DECLARE days,next_diff int;

    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS calc AS (SELECT p.pid,p_date,days,next_diff,cur_depre,cur_wtvalue,next_depre,next_wtvalue,accum_depre,pro_loss,c.cid,p.added_date,c.category_life,p.depre,p.sale_status,p.sale_date,p.sale_amount from products p,products d,categories c WHERE p.pid=d.pid AND p.cid=c.cid 
     );
     INSERT INTO calc (PID) 
    SELECT PID FROM products WHERE PID NOT IN (SELECT PID FROM calc);
    UPDATE calc set days = datediff(p_date,added_date);
    UPDATE calc set days = 0 WHERE datediff(p_date,added_date) < 0;
    UPDATE calc set next_diff = datediff(sale_date,DATE_ADD(p_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY) );
    UPDATE calc set next_diff = datediff('2019-03-31',added_date) WHERE added_date>p_date;
    UPDATE calc set cur_depre = (depre/category_life)*datediff(p_date,added_date);

    UPDATE calc set cur_depre = 0 where (depre/category_life)*datediff(p_date,added_date)<0;

    UPDATE calc set cur_wtvalue =(depre-(depre/category_life)*datediff(p_date,added_date)); 

    UPDATE calc set cur_wtvalue = 0 WHERE added_date>p_date;

    UPDATE calc set next_depre =( (depre/category_life)*datediff(sale_date,DATE_ADD(p_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY) )) where added_date < p_date;

    UPDATE calc set next_depre =( (depre/category_life) * datediff('2019-03-31',added_date)) WHERE added_Date > p_date;

    UPDATE calc SET next_wtvalue = depre -(depre/category_life)*datediff(p_date,added_date) - (( (depre/category_life)*datediff(sale_date,DATE_ADD(p_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY) )) );
    UPDATE calc SET next_wtvalue = depre - (( (depre/category_life) * datediff('2019-03-31',added_date)))  WHERE added_date>p_date;

    UPDATE calc SET accum_depre = ((depre/category_life)*datediff(p_date,added_date))+( (depre/category_life)*datediff(sale_date,DATE_ADD(p_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY) )) ;
    UPDATE calc SET accum_depre =( (depre/category_life) * datediff('2019-03-31',added_date))  WHERE added_Date > p_date;

    UPDATE calc SET pro_loss = sale_amount-(depre -(depre/category_life)*datediff(p_date,added_date) - (( (depre/category_life)*datediff(sale_date,DATE_ADD(p_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY) )) ) ); 

    UPDATE calc SET pro_loss = 0 WHERE sale_status=0;
    SELECT * from calc;

    END
```